# keyboard/mouse switch that simulates devices to connected computers and does not disconnect keyboard/mouse on switch

Tags: usb, mice, kvm

I have a USB hub where I can switch between two computers. On pressing a button, the hub disconnects all devices from one computer and then, after a short time, reconnects them to the other computer. Video switching is not necessary!

I am searching a device that simulates a keyboard and mouse to both computers, i.e. both computers see a plugged-in keyboard and mouse all the time. Events from the real keyboard/mouse  are then relayed to the currently selected computer.

I know that keyboards have state and more sophisticated gaming mice might also have that. But I am not convinced this problem cannot be solved somehow, hence my question:

Does such a thing exist? If yes, which models are of interest?

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be referring to [dynamic device mapping technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_device_mapping). If so, that's very much a thing.

I could recommend [ConnectPro's VGA+USB KVMs](https://connectpro.com/kvm-switches/usb-switches/?v=7516fd43adaa). To the best of my knowledge they don't have USB-only KVMs, so [UR-12](https://connectpro.com/product/ur-12/?v=7516fd43adaa) seems to be the the least feature-full model - it has 2 USB ports + 1 VGA port.

I know for a fact that proper keyboard + mouse switching is a non-trivial task and many KVMs fail at it (such as Jide Tech JD-72UA, which I own).

Disclaimer: I don't own a ConnectPro KVM at the time of writing (but I intend to buy one soon).

Comment: From what I understand DDM is the best option, but it would suffice to have peripheral emulation for mouse and keyboard already. This should make the switch cheaper, right?

Comment: Have you tried one of the ConnectPro KVMs without any video connected, just for keyboard and mouse switching?  Does it work for that?  If so what model do you have?

Comment: @CroadLangshan I have not strictly speaking, but I don't use the video switching capabilities as of now (I have some wires connected, but it shouldn't matter). Yes, the devices switch between 2 Linux and 1 Windows boxes without an issue. I think at some point the devices were reconnecting, but cannot tell for sure at this point. I have UDP2-14AP.